# MongoDB query index with $gt and $ne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing

### Query

I have a query like this:

```
db.sample.find({
  bool1: false,
  theNull: null,
  existing: {$ne: null},
  $or: [
    { bool2: false, string: {$in: [<array of strings>]}},
    { bool2: true, string: {$in: [<array of different strings>]}}
  ],
  dateField: {$lt: ISODate(<Given date>)}
}).sort({dateField: -1});
```

### Question

I'm looking to build an optimal index query for that. I hit that query a lot, and I wanna do better.

### Parts of query

My documents have in majority of cases (99.9+ %) the `bool1` set to `false` and `theNull` is null, and `existing` is in 95% cases not null - so I need those fields (somewhere) to filter this out.

`dateField` is what I sort by. Now, my interesting data set is with `string` and `bool2` - there's where I have variations on the docs and that's basically what the query is filtering.

`string` is always from a relatively contained set of strings (usernames actually) and `bool2` is true in very low number of docs.

`dateField` is mostly sequential together with actual insertion time, but there are gaps here and there, as in I have to move the date back a few months for a series of 10-100 documents.

### What I did so far

The best results so far is setting these indexes:

```
{ string: 1, bool2: 1, creation_time: 1}
```

in combination (ORed) with

```
{string: 1, bool2: 1}
```

I'm not sure what best indexing strategy to use with this specific query.

I've tried moving a lot of things up and down in the query (eg. moving the `existing` all the way down or just bellow the $or).

Also, I've tried adding indexes to all those fields in various combos. What I most often end up with when running explain, is using the index that is set on my `string` and `bool2` ORed to another index or `string`, `bool2` and `dateField`.

And I can put `bool`, `theNull`, `existing`, or various combos of those in front of that index, but they don't get used.

I wonder why is that and if I'd get better performance (or less fetched docs if that matters) if I could a more wide index on those docs.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the first index I would try:

```
{ string: 1, creation_time: -1}
```

As most of your variation is in `string` it is the best column to filter on. I have also added `creation_time` in descending order as performance is better when query order and index order match.

You may get better result by including `bool2` as well:

```
{ string: 1, bool2: 1, creation_time: -1}
```

Comment: Yeah, none of it helps much, I did those already, but I think the `.sort()` is killing me.

Comment: Without .sort() I actually get good results, something like 5000 index/doc scans for 4600 results. But with sort, it goes south.

Comment: Did you try this index ?: `{ creation_time: -1, string : 1}`